# SQL Server : find duplicate record by column value

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a value like below dataset. Now how I can find the duplicate DataSetID like: 201 & 401 is duplicate record.

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `PIVOT` and `ROW_Number`

**For Non Duplicates**

**[FIDDLE DEMO](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=8c606758501a9e569de6e627c2c7b986)**

```
SELECT * FROm Tbl WHERE DateSetID IN 
(
    SELECT DateSetID FROM 
    (
       SELECT DateSetID,[Name], [Age], [Gender],ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY [Name], [Age], 
        [Gender] ORDER BY DateSetID) RN
    FROM  (SELECT * FROM Tbl) AS SourceTable  
    PIVOT(MAX(ColumnB) FOR ColumnA IN ([Name], [Age], [Gender])
    ) AS PivotTable)Tmp WHERE RN = 1
);
```

**For Duplicates alone**

**[FIDDLE DEMO](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=63cb22ff076f97a01637e2d82b7c16e0)**

```
SELECT T.* FROM Tbl T JOIN (
SELECT DatasetID, ColumnA, ColumnB
FROM 
(
   SELECT DatasetID, [Name], [Age], [Gender], ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY [Name], [Age], [Gender] ORDER BY DatasetID) RN
   FROM  (SELECT * FROM Tbl) AS SourceTable  
    PIVOT(MAX(ColumnB) FOR ColumnA IN ([Name], [Age], [Gender])) AS PivotTable
)Tmp 
UNPIVOT
(
    ColumnB
    FOR ColumnA in ([Name], [Age], [Gender])
) AS UnpivotOp
WHERE RN > 1
)X ON T.ColumnA = X.ColumnA AND T.ColumnB = X.ColumnB;
```

Comment: @RedDevil Sorry, I though of removing duplicates. I have updated now.

Comment: Thanks for your ans. it's working fine. But, i need another query .like: if all the column's record is same then return the DataSetID.mean, if the value of  Name, Age & Gender of all column is same then return DataSetID. In current Query, if any one value is equal to other then returen the DatasetID. If you change the value of AGE to 36 (which uniqueID =5)    then all Dataset Value Shows 201,301,401 . But i need the DataSetID (201 , 401) if all the value of Name,Age & Gender is same.Thanks is advance.

Answer (score 1):

You need to count pivoted rows using ubounded rows window (default)

```
SELECT * 
FROm Tbl 
WHERE DatasetID IN (
    SELECT DatasetID 
    FROM (
       SELECT DatasetID, [Name], [Age], [Gender]
         ,count(*) OVER (PARTITION BY [Name], [Age], [Gender]) cnt
       FROM Tbl  
       PIVOT(MAX(ColumnB) FOR ColumnA IN ([Name], [Age], [Gender])
     ) AS PivotTable
    )Tmp 
    WHERE cnt > 1
);
```

[Fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=6d4cc49e65fd79a46ba3de0444e96d76)

Answer (score 0):

`concat` the columns, and apply `group by`.

```
select distinct Datesetid from tableA
where concat(columnA, columnB) in (
    select  concat(columnA, columnB) from
    tableA
    group by concat(columnA, columnB)
    having count(1) > 1)
```

see [dbfiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=303d73a28ffdb2b148c434319ef481c2).

Comment: sorry, may be i don't get you. where i can use group by?i run the query and getting the error like: Column 'tableA' is invalid in the select list because it is not contained in either an aggregate function or the GROUP BY clause.

Comment: @riad, group by will group the `count()` per same `concat(DateSetID, ColumnA, ColumnB)`

Comment: @metal, could you please update the query. Still don't get you and facing the error.

Comment: @metal: Column 'tableA.DateSetID' is invalid in the select list because it is not contained in either an aggregate function or the GROUP BY clause.

Comment: @riad, can you try dbfiddle i provided.

Answer (score 0):

write give below query & find duplicate value in table

SELECT DISTINCT FirstName, LastName, MobileNo FROM CUSTOMER;