# SQL Server: Match two tables and get value

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have two tables shown below. Now I just need to search and match of **Table A** with **Table B** and identify the exact matching record set from **Table B**.

Like: Search the  *Name*, *Age* and *Sex* values of **Table A** into **Table B** and Identify the exact matching records of **TableB**.

As here Only *301* & *501* are the exactly same as *101* record of **Table A**.

Thanks in advance.

***Note***: I had already asked a question on this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59403985/sql-server-find-duplicate-record-by-column-value). But both questions are different.

[image]

[image]

Comment: Most people here want sample table data and the expected result as formatted text, not images.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get the matches using `join` and aggregation:

```
select a.datasetid, b.datasetid
from a join
     b
     on a.columna = b.columna and 
        a.columnb = b.columnb
group by a.datasetid, b.datasetid
having count(*) = (select count(*) from a a2 where a2.datasetid = a.datasetid);
```

Note:  This returns as matches even when `b` has additional rows.  That makes sense to me.  Also, this assumes that a given `columna` only appears once for each data set id (in either table).

This gives the values in separate rows.  You can re-aggregate to get your final result:

```
select datasetid_a, string_agg(datasetid_b, ',')
from (select a.datasetid as datasetid_a, b.datasetid as datasetid_b
      from a join
           b
           on a.columna = b.columna and 
              a.columnb = b.columnb
      group by a.datasetid, b.datasetid
      having count(*) = (select count(*) from a a2 where a2.datasetid = a.datasetid)
     ) ab
group by datasetid_a;
```

`string_agg()` is not available in older versions of SQL Server.  To be honest, in those versions, I would stick with the results in separate rows.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. it's working fine. But , i am using Sql Server 2012. string_agg() is not working here. Is there any other way to concat the datasetid of TableB .

Answer (score 2):

You can try the below query. Here I have used a simple query shown below to get all the records that exist in both tables.

```
SELECT DISTINCT DataSetId AS SearchId, FindinValues
FROM (
Select 
      TableA.*,
      TableB.DataSetId as FindinValues,
      ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION By TableB.DataSetId Order By TableB.DataSetId) RN
from TableA
inner join TableB on TableA.ColumnA = TableB.ColumnA
and TableA.ColumnB = TableB.ColumnB
)a where RN = (Select Count(*) from tableA)
```

The output of the above query is as shown below.

```
SearchId    FindinValues
------------------------
101         301
101         501
```

Now to get the above table into comma separated group by search id you have two choices in terms of simplicity i.e., you can consider your above query as a table or you can insert the above query records into a temporary table and run the below query on that.

```
-- To get the data in comma separated which exists in both the table.
SELECT SearchId, FindinValues = 
    STUFF((SELECT ', ' + Cast(FindinValues as Varchar(20))
           FROM (SELECT DISTINCT DataSetId AS SearchId, FindinValues
FROM (
Select 
      TableA.*,
      TableB.DataSetId as FindinValues,
      ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION By TableB.DataSetId Order By TableB.DataSetId) RN
from TableA
inner join TableB on TableA.ColumnA = TableB.ColumnA
and TableA.ColumnB = TableB.ColumnB
)a where RN = (Select Count(*) from tableA)) b 
           WHERE b.SearchId = a.SearchId 
          FOR XML PATH('')), 1, 2, '')
FROM (SELECT DISTINCT DataSetId AS SearchId, FindinValues
FROM (
Select 
      TableA.*,
      TableB.DataSetId as FindinValues,
      ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION By TableB.DataSetId Order By TableB.DataSetId) RN
from TableA
inner join TableB on TableA.ColumnA = TableB.ColumnA
and TableA.ColumnB = TableB.ColumnB
)a where RN = (Select Count(*) from tableA)) a
GROUP BY SearchId
```

This will give output as shown below.

```
SearchId    FindinValues
------------------------
101         301, 501
```

You can find the live [**demo here**](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=6eecfae5a437e07165fbfdd49ae5e654).

Here is another way with a shorter code.

```
SELECT DISTINCT DataSetId AS SearchId, FindinValues into #TempResult
FROM (
Select 
      TableA.*,
      TableB.DataSetId as FindinValues,
      ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION By TableB.DataSetId Order By TableB.DataSetId) RN
from TableA
inner join TableB on TableA.ColumnA = TableB.ColumnA
and TableA.ColumnB = TableB.ColumnB
)a where RN = (Select Count(*) from tableA)

-- To get the data in comma separated which exists in both the table.
Select * from #TempResult

SELECT SearchId, FindinValues = 
    STUFF((SELECT ', ' + Cast(FindinValues as Varchar(10))
           FROM #TempResult b 
           WHERE b.SearchId = a.SearchId 
          FOR XML PATH('')), 1, 2, '')
FROM #TempResult a
GROUP BY SearchId
```

You can find this [**demo here**](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=5dff00073de9dad661f6cdfaa447ccc3). This will run in the lower version of SQL Server also.

Comment: @riad Thanks to let me know and happy to hear that.